# Security Best Practices for Email-based User Registration?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, csrf

I have a website, and want to register new users.  The registration process is as follows:

1. User enters email address, clicks 'Register'
2. email address is sent to server
3. Server generates a registration code, stores a hashed version
4. Server sends an email containing a link:  `confirm?code=<reg_code>`
5. User checks email, clicks link
6. Server receives request, confirms validity of code
7. Server stores email address as a user id
8. Server issues token, stores token, sends response with token
9. User's browser stores token as a cookie
10. Cookie is used as a Bearer token for authentication in subsequent requests.

I was wondering if there is any way to improve the security of this approach.  Here are some considerations:

- Manual cut-and-paste of code, with session-id check

In step 4, instead of providing a link `confirm?code=<reg_code>`, the email could contain a link to a 'code submission' page which says "Please cut-and-paste the code in your email here, and click submit".  This way, javascript could grab a session cookie that was previously generated and stored during step 1.  Then, the server could validate that the session cookies match between requests.

- 2FA

After the user clicks the original email link, the system could ask for a second factor confirmation.

It seems that the Manual cut-and-paste with session-id check takes care of a stolen email scenario, because that would fail the session-id check.

And, 2FA requires the hacker to hack a second channel, or to steal a device.  Both of these measures seem extremely secure.

However, the Manual cut-and-paste is onerous for the user, and the 2FA is annoying because it must ask the user for a phone number or to install some authenticator app.

Is there any other way?

Comment: So each time user come to your website the whole logic is repeated or the same token in phase 8 is send back ?

Comment: same token is used until it expires.  then the user must do the whole flow again.  not the most elegant.  but, it avoids requiring the user to have an account with google or facebook or github, etc.  only email.